# How to Add Expires headers

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, expires-header, w3-total-cache

I'm using this code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 3 days"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/x-ico "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header unset ETag
   Header unset Pragma
   Header unset Last-Modified
   Header append Cache-Control "public, no-transform, must-revalidate"
   Header set Last-modified "Tue, 1 Aug 2016 10:10:10 GMT"
 </IfModule>
 </IfModule>
```

But gtmetrix.com  and tools.pingdom.com shows 5 static components without a far-future expiration date.

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:regular,700
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js
http://c.statcounter.com/t.php?sc_project=11059157&java=1&security=2d5e45b2&u1=D82D61ABF18A4FF9620A96B3F31C97F5&sc_random=0.5705474616082253&jg=new&rr=1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1&resolution=1024&h=861&camefrom=&u=http%3A//hddregenerator.net/&t=HDD%20REGENERATOR.%2015%25%20Discount%20%7C%20HDD%20Regenerator%20for%20%2484.99.%20Free%20Demo%20download.%2030-day%20money%20back%20guarantee.%20Free%201%20year%20minor%20update.%20Unlimited%20license%20period.&rcat=d&rdom=d&rdomg=new&bb=1&sc_snum=1&sess=a181b5&p=0&invisible=1
```

How to add expire headers for these 5 components?!

Comment: you can use one of the plugin for same 
W3 Total Cache
WP Super Cache
WP Rocket

Comment: I use the total cash but get the message about the expires header anyway.

Comment: try to install WP Super Cache

Comment: Hello @Merkucio, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?
I am already using the WP Super Cache plugin.

Comment: Hello. No, I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't add expire headers to those 5 components, simply because they aren't on your own server, and therefore you have no control over them.

If you're looking for a great expire headers plugin, I recommend [Far Future Expiry Header](https://wordpress.org/plugins/far-future-expiry-header/).